# Why are columns 2, 3, 4 are shifted over on my HTML calculator?

Tags: html

Thank you in advance for the help, I'm making a simple html calculator and though it works, columns 2, 3, 4 are shifted over to the right as shown below in the image provided. I have included everything, I'm sure this is a simple mistake but I can't seem to find what's causing the shift. Thank you so much for the help!!

[The index.htm file when opened in a web browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diS3V.png)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <form name="calculator">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="two" value ="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="minus" value="-" onclick="calculator.display.value += '-'"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="times" value="x" onclick="calculator.display.value += '*'"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="calculator.display.value = ''"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="doit" value="=" onclick="calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="div" value="/" onclick="calculator.display.value += '/'"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: because the large input is in the first column

Answer (score 2):

The large input textbox element is in the first column. So it makes all the other rows have the same width. You can use colspan to make the first row span multiple columns.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <form name="calculator">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
              <input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="two" value ="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="minus" value="-" onclick="calculator.display.value += '-'"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="times" value="x" onclick="calculator.display.value += '*'"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="calculator.display.value = ''"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="doit" value="=" onclick="calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="div" value="/" onclick="calculator.display.value += '/'"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add colspan to make the top row span all 4 columns of the table; like below:

The reason this is happening is because your table is expecting 4 columns per row and the first row only has one td i.e. one column; if you set colspan to 4 it will span all 4 columns of the table

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <form name="calculator">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
              <input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="two" value ="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'"></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="button" name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'"></td>
           <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="minus" value="-" onclick="calculator.display.value += '-'"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="times" value="x" onclick="calculator.display.value += '*'"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="calculator.display.value = ''"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'"></td>
          <td><input type="button" name="doit" value="=" onclick="calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value)"></td>
          <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="div" value="/" onclick="calculator.display.value += '/'"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Look into using CSS and styling the content on your page. The buttons are shifting because of your input field by the looks of it.